# Python code doesn't return expected results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've encountered a problem with my code:

```
def zeroOrOne(x):
    i = 0
    zc = 0
    oc = 0
    while i < len(x):
        if x[i] == "1":
            oc = oc + 1
        elif x[i] == "0":
            zc = zc + 1
        i = i + 1
    if zc > oc: 
        return True 
    elif oc > zc:
       return False
    elif oc == zc:
        return False
f = open("D:\matura\Dane_PR2\liczby.txt", "r") 
for x in f.readlines():
    print(zeroOrOne(x))
    
    
f.close()
```

whereas the opened file contains following numbers saved as strings:

```
11010100111
11110111111011101
1010100111010100
1101111111111111111111010100101010101001
1010110011001101010011110101010101010111
```

My goal is to count each zero and one in these lines and then decide whether there are more ones or zeroes. If there are more zeros I want the function to return **TRUE** Unluckily it doesn't work.
It says that all the lines equal **FALSE** which is not true, since 3 of the lines are supposed to return True.

Comment: None of the examples in your strings have more zeros than ones.  Your code works for a line like `0000000000000000111`.

Comment: All your examples have more ones than zeroes. Your code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It says that all the lines equal FALSE which is not true, since 3 of the lines are supposed to return True.

Have you actually checked? In the data you provide all lines have more 1s than 0s. You can determine this easily using `str.count`:

```py
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for x in f:
        print(x.count('0'), x.count('1'))
```

=>

```
4 7
3 14
8 8
11 29
17 23
```

That aside, your code would benefit from various improvements (aside from the ones you can see in the short snippet above):

- your naming is somewhat obscure
- strings are iterable and yield characters, no need to index manually
- `<=` and `>=` are valid operators, you don't need to check for `<` and `==` separately (also you can use the reverse operation: `not a >= b` is `a < b`)
- you can directly return the result of boolean operations

```py
def moreZeroes(s):
    zeroes, ones = 0, 0
    for c in s:
        if c == '0':
            zeroes += 1
        if c == '1':
            ones += 1
    return zeroes > ones
```

Or the short version using the standard facilities, which is probably faster due to executing entirely in C despite traversing the string twice:

```py
def moreZeroes(s):
    return s.count('0') > s.count('1')
```

or, probably not cheaper for just two counts especially if your input is not humongous:

```py
def moreZeroes(s):
    c = collections.Counter(s)
    return c['0'] > c['1']
```

Comment: Oh my God, Yea... I had a different set of data saved in the file and didn't check properly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help and tips, I'm totally new so it's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = """11010100111
11110111111011101
1010100111010100
1101111111111111111111010100101010101001
1010110011001101010011110101010101010111"""

for line_number, line in enumerate(lines.splitlines()):
    ones = line.count('1')
    zeros = line.count('0')

    print('Line %d has %d zeros and %d ones, it should return %s' % (line_number, zeros, ones, str(True if zeros > ones else False)))
```

->

```
Line 0 has 4 zeros and 7 ones, it should return False
Line 1 has 3 zeros and 14 ones, it should return False
Line 2 has 8 zeros and 8 ones, it should return False
Line 3 has 11 zeros and 29 ones, it should return False
Line 4 has 17 zeros and 23 ones, it should return False
```

So your method `zeroOrOne()` would beL

```
def zeroOrOne(line):
    ones = line.count('1')
    zeros = line.count('0')

    return True if zeros > ones else False
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest solution, just for the sake of it:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    [print(l.count("0") > l.count("1")) for l in f]
```

Comment: Haha, thank you! Seeing it done in 2 lines makes me want to learn more :D